# MYSQL: Display NULL value when foreing key is NULL

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-key, php, null

I have the following database structure in MYSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE xs_bugtracking ( 
                    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
                    `product` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                    `title` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
                    `status` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
                    `descr` VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
                    `assignee` INT(11),
                    `reported_by` INT(11) NOT NULL,
                    `importance` VARCHAR(8),
                    `create_date` INT(11) NOT NULL,
                    `modify_date` INT(11) NOT NULL
                    );
```

The fields `assignee` and `reported_by` are foreing key of the same table of wordpress db: [wp_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users)

Now i want get all element with the following SELECT query:

```
SELECT xs_bugtracking.id, product, xs_bugtracking.title AS title, status, xs_bugtracking.descr AS descr,
            assignee_tbl.user_nicename AS assignee,reported_tbl.user_nicename AS reported_by,importance,
            FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'create_date', FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'modify_date' 
            FROM xs_bugtracking, xs_products, wp_users AS assignee_tbl,
            wp_users AS reported_tbl WHERE 
            xs_products.name=product AND xs_products.lang='en' AND
            (xs_bugtracking.assignee=assignee_tbl.ID OR ISNULL(xs_bugtracking.assignee)) AND
            xs_bugtracking.reported_by=reported_tbl.ID
```

Now, problems come when you have a row with `assignee` equals to `NULL`, infact the resulting table multiplies the rows when the value is `NULL`, because lost the JOIN from `wp_users` aka `assignee_tbl`.

There is a way to display `assignee_tbl.user_nicename` when `assignee` is not `NULL` and just `NULL` when `assignee` is `NULL`?

If you want check the [full source code](https://gitlab.com/xsoftware/xsoftware-wordpress-bugtracking)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the ANSI join that was introduced in SQL92. If you use a LEFT JOIN I think you achieve what you want:

```
SELECT xs_bugtracking.id, product
     , xs_bugtracking.title AS title
     , status
     , xs_bugtracking.descr AS descr
     , assignee_tbl.user_nicename AS assignee
     , reported_tbl.user_nicename AS reported_by
     , importance
     , FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'create_date'
     , FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'modify_date' 
FROM xs_bugtracking
JOIN xs_products
    ON xs_bugtracking.product = xs_products.name 
LEFT JOIN wp_users AS assignee_tbl
    ON xs_bugtracking.assignee = assignee_tbl.ID
JOIN wp_users AS reported_tbl 
    ON xs_bugtracking.reported_by=reported_tbl.ID 
WHERE xs_products.lang='en'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 joins using the old (implicit join) syntax that uses a comma separated list of tables in the `FROM` clause and the joining conditions in the `WHERE` clause:

```
FROM
    xs_bugtracking,
    xs_products,
    wp_users AS assignee_tbl,
    wp_users AS reported_tbl

WHERE 
      xs_products.name = product
  AND xs_products.lang = 'en'

  AND ( xs_bugtracking.assignee = assignee_tbl.ID
     OR ISNULL(xs_bugtracking.assignee)
      )

  AND xs_bugtracking.reported_by = reported_tbl.ID
```

While the syntax is valid, it allows only `CROSS` and `INNER` joins. In this case, it makes the (implicit) joins to be `INNER` joins. By the description of your issue, you need `OUTER` joins instead. So, the solution is to explixitly use `LEFT` (outer) joins:

```
FROM
    xs_bugtracking

  LEFT JOIN xs_products
  ON  xs_products.name = xs_bugtracking.product
  AND xs_products.lang = 'en'

  LEFT JOIN wp_users AS assignee_tbl
  ON xs_bugtracking.assignee = assignee_tbl.ID

  LEFT JOIN wp_users AS reported_tbl
  ON xs_bugtracking.reported_by = reported_tbl.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently your SQL Selected statement is an [Inner Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). You need to refactor to use an outer join. I would suggest using alias where appropriate to help make the code mode readable.

```
SELECT 
    XSBug.id, 
    XSBug.product, 
    XSBug.title AS title, 
    status, 
    xs_bugtracking.descr AS descr,
    assignee_tbl.user_nicename AS assignee,
    reported_tbl.user_nicename AS reported_by,
    importance,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'create_date', 
    FROM_UNIXTIME(create_date) AS 'modify_date' 
FROM 
    xs_bugtracking XSBug
JOIN
    xs_products XSProd
ON
    XSPRod.Name = XSBug.Product AND xs_products.lang='en'
JOIN
    wp_users AS reported_tbl 
ON  
    XSBug.reported_by=reported_tbl.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        wp_users AS assignee_tbl
ON
    XSBug = assignee_tbl.ID
```